# Django project: No post found matching the query error

Tags: django, post, view

**Problem:** I am trying to retreive a detail view (singular blog post) by placing the following url in the browser:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/post/1/
```

It should retrieve and render the first blog post on the screen, however, it comes up with the following error:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/post/1/
Raised by:  socialmedia.views.PostDetailView
No post found matching the query
```

**Update**, as per Daniel Roseman's comment below. I get the error says I don't have a post with id 1, but clearly I don't understand the implementation of posts, as I assumed when a post was created it was automatically assigned an ID in the db. It would be helpful if a solution contained a clear explanation of what I am missing in my understanding here as a beginner.

I've looked in the admin, clicking into posts, and cannot find the ID number anywhere either.

[image]

I have looked through the code and have created the view correctly, as far as I can see, and also have the route (in urls) that should call the view.

**Question:** Can someone point out the error please? Could you also provide a useful explanation to aid understanding in this specific example (routing, query matching posts etc)

I have looked at similar questions and answers but cannot quite find the solution to this. A similar question suggested it may be to do with the admin or routes, but used regular expressions in the urls.py suggesting an older version of Django which is of no use to me.

**urls.py**

```
#THIS IS THE SOCIAL MEDIA URLS ..not the root directory URLS
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . views import PostListView,PostDetailView
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('', PostListView.as_view(), name='socialmedia-home'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
    path('about/', views.about, name='socialmedia-about'), 
]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Post #import the Models Post
from django.views.generic import ListView,DetailView


from django.http import HttpResponse
# Create your views here.

class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post #what model to query in order to create the list
    template_name = 'socialmedia/home.html' """<app>/<model>_<viewtype>.html
    in this case would be socialmedia/post_detail.html
    """
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']

class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post 

def about(request):
    return render(request,'socialmedia/about.html',{'title':'About'})
```

**post_detail.html**

```
{% extends "socialmedia/base.html" %}
{% block content %}

    <article class="media content-section">
        <img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="{{object.author.profile.image.url}}">
    <div class="media-body">
        <div class="article-metadata">
      <a class="mr-2" href="#">{{ object.author }}</a>
      <small class="text-muted">{{ object.date_posted|date:"F d, Y"}}</small>
    </div>
    <h2 class="article-title">{{ object.title }}</h2>
    <p class="article-content">{{ object.content }}</p>
  </div>
</article>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: What is unclear about the error? You don't have a post with id 1.

Comment: @DanielRoseman - I assumed an ID was automatically assigned, and I do have four posts in the admin panel relating to these objects. Could you please suggest what I need to check/implement as I'm sure I'm missing something fundamental about the structure and set up/implementation of these posts.

Comment: The id is automatically assigned. But why do you think it is 1? If you click on the post in the admin, or in the list view, you will see in the URL the actual IDs for the posts you have.

Comment: Why would I think it was 1? I only have 4, and assuming it started sequentially, 1 seems obvious. Secondly, it is also on the tutorial I'm following. I've updated my answer to show the admin panel - cannot find where to retrieve or see the ID of a post.

Comment: Your URL says /post/8. So 8 is the ID. But again, you already have a ListView, you presumably have a link from there to the DetailView - if you followed that link it would have automatically inserted the correct ID.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't look in the URL. So IDs do not automatically update if earlier posts are deleted, I assume. Isn't this a flaw and again, where can these be changed, as there is no editing IDs in the admin. For a beginner, understanding these things is very useful (it's not plainly obvious!)

Comment: No, it's not a flaw. IDs are unique and need to remain constant, there is no way of changing them. But probably later in your tutorial it will show you how to link using a better URL, ie a slug like you see in the URL for this question.

Answer (score 1):

You got this error beacause the id value you are trying to pass in the url is not present in your database. I had the similar issue and went on to see the id value and passed in with correct url it worked.

In case you don't know how to see id value you can follow the steps:

1. enter the shell `python manage.py shell`
2. import the model inside the shell. `from your_app_name.models import Post`
3. `Post.objects.all()[0].id` this will give you the id of first item on your table and you can enter that
   or
   `Post.objects.values()` this will display all the data in your table with field name.